# Using word "adept" or "whiz"

Tags: word-usage

Is it grammatically correct to use the words "adept" or "whiz" for describing a person that is an expert in a domain, for example:

- This is a computer safety whiz.
- This is a computer safety adept.
- This is a health adept.
- ...

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Whiz" is causal.  It is fine for spoken English or even casual emails, but not for formal writing.

"Adept" is a rather formal sounding word.  Though I'd prefer "an adept in computer safety".

In plain speech "expert" is usually preferred, or provide the actual skills

> He is a health care expert.
>
> He is a grade 8 registered nurse.  (this is clearer and more precise than "health care expert", provided your audience knows the grading system in nursing.)

Answer (score -1):

"Adept" in this context has an odd feel to it. It sounds like it comes from a fantasy novel or a computer game or something like that.

"Whiz" is normal but quite casual. The most natural word is probably "expert" but you could use "maven", "guru", "virtuoso", "authority" and so on.

Comment: Adept is a normal English word that considerably pre-dates fantasy novels and computer games.